# Why my function return value when I release the key?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, key, p5.js

I know this could be a stupid question, but I can't figure out what's happening with my code in p5.js (I use the online editor).

I'm making a simple snake game but when I call the function to add a certain value to move the head (for now just the head) it returns the value I want but does it another time when I release the key despite I also called this:

```
function keyReleased(){
    return false;
  }
```

These are the functions that I call in the sketch file.

```
let w = 87;
let a = 65;
let s = 83;
let d = 68;
let stepToDo = 10;

function keyPressed(axis){
  if (axis === 0){
    if(keyCode === a){
      keyCode = 0;
      return -stepToDo;
    } else if(keyCode === d){
      keyCode = 0;
      return stepToDo;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  } else if (axis === 1) {
    if(keyCode === w){
      keyCode = 0;
      return -stepToDo;
    } else if(keyCode === s){
      keyCode = 0;
      return stepToDo;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

function keyReleased(){
    return false;
  }
```

This is the sketch file.

```
let arrTest = [200, 200];


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  arrTest[0] = arrTest[0] + keyPressed(0);
  arrTest[1] = arrTest[1] + keyPressed(1);
  keyReleased();
  //console.log(arrTest);

  rect (arrTest[0], arrTest[1], 10, 10);
}
```

Link to the sketch itself https://editor.p5js.org/antolab/sketches/_Lzz41cos

Comment: so,Why don't you build your code around keyRealeased() instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`keyPressed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/keyPressed) function is an [event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp).
You don't have to call it from your main `draw()` loop; instead, it is automatically called every time a key is pressed. That way you can use it to change your position array depending on the input key. For example as follows:

```
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === a) {
    arrTest[0] = arrTest[0] - stepToDo;
  } else if (keyCode === d) {
    arrTest[0] = arrTest[0] + stepToDo;
  } else if (keyCode === w) {
    arrTest[1] = arrTest[1] - stepToDo;
  } else if (keyCode === s) {
    arrTest[1] = arrTest[1] + stepToDo;
  }
}
```

Note that because we do not define a new `arrTest` variable within the `keyPressed()` function it will automatically access the variable that you defined further above.
[Here](https://editor.p5js.org/janmaltel/sketches/CT7kxkhMI) is the corresponding modified sketch.

The reason the keyPressed() function was seemingly executed ``twice'' in your code is that it got executed as part of *every* iteration of the `draw()` loop **and** automatically upon pressing a key.